# Background image add in website in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I was trying to set background image in my website

but in `style.css` file is not visible it has this error is `"Cannot reslove directory 'Images'`

**CSS:**

`background: white url("images/one.png") no-repeat right bottom;`

**index.html:**

`{% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'music/style.css' %}"/>`

I want to select image from `music/images/one.png`
Thanks is advance

Comment: Shouldn't it be `url("music/images/one.png")` ?

Comment: tried this but still exist same problem and it has red marked under line under music/images/one.png

Comment: Please, post your folder tree and if you are working on debug mode or not.

Comment: give this a try url(./images/one.png)

Comment: I doubt the actual error you got used the mispelt "reslove", please try to make an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your folder layout, however have you tried providing it with the full URL to the file? If that doesn't work, provided it's sensible for your folder structure you can try relative paths, for instance `"../images/one.png"`

Comment: I have tried this 
music/images/one.png  &
static/music/images/one.png

my music folder is in static folder
but dosen`t work  it has red marked under line under music/images/one.png

Comment: And no luck I assume? What if you take the entirety of the path, for instance if you were running windows `C:\\Users\\Path\\To\\File` or `/var/www/html/path/to/file` on ubuntu etc..